# Add image dynamically to wx.StaticBitmap?

Tags: python, wxpython

It is possible to add dynamically images to wx.StaticBitmap?

Now I can only add one image and only change existing image.

I want to display next image after new line or something else.

My actual code:

```
self.images = wx.StaticBitmap(self, id=-1, pos=wx.DefaultPosition,
                            size=(-1,100),
                            style= wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
data = open(imagename,"rb").read()
stream = cStringIO.StringIO(data)
image = wx.ImageFromStream(stream)
image.Rescale(77,57)
bmp = wx.BitmapFromImage( image)
self.images.SetBitmap(bmp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could possibly include more than one image in a `wx.StaticBitmap`.

However, you could:

- dynamically create the image that you are going to display in the `StaticBitmap`, using PIL or something to "concatenate" the images
- just display multiple `wx.StaticBitmap`s in a `wx.Sizer` of some kind